# How many items can be taken from an array with given order size

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array including numbers where the array order is fixed.

I would like to see how many of item I can take from this array with my ordersize in JS

My code gives wrong results, for example 500 units can buy first 2 items and 0,66 of 3rd item so total 2,66 can be taken but code gives 4. For 250 unit I can take 1st item full and 0,75 of second item total 1,75 can be taken but code gives 1.5.

For 300 gives 2 this is true but generally gives wrong result.

I've changed the line of result inside or out side of for and if conditions, it affects result but again the results are wrong (for given array 2100 unit ordersize will take all items with 6 results)

```js
function calculateOrder() {
  var coinArray = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
  var orderSize = 500;
  var sum = 0;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < coinArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sum < orderSize) {
      sum += coinArray[i];
    }
    return i + (orderSize - sum) / coinArray[i];
  }
}
document.write(calculateOrder());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below. I fixed a few things for you.

1. Create a variable to store the **current amount** of money that you have. So every time you "buy" an item, you subtract what you bought.
2. I changed some of the logic to make it work. Basically the return statement **divides your current amount of money by the required amount** to get the portion of the item you can buy, and then a**dds the amount of items that you've already bought**.
3. Also, you need to have the else there. The else executes when the **if statement results to false**, so the else executes when you don't have enough money to buy the item.
4. `return` **breaks out** of your function, so that's one of the reasons your previous code wasn't working correctly. The for loop would **execute once** and then break out.
5. The `for` loop needs to end at `coinArray.length`. You probably thought you needed the `- 1` there since array index's start at 0, except since the for loop is **less than** and not **less than or equal to**, it will end at the last index.

```js
function calculateOrder(orderSize) {
  var coinArray = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
  var amountOfMoney = orderSize;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < coinArray.length; i++) {
    if (amountOfMoney > coinArray[i]) {
      amountOfMoney -= coinArray[i];
    }
    else {
      return i + amountOfMoney / coinArray[i];
    }
  }
}
document.write(calculateOrder(500));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three issues:

- `for` loop executes the `if` statement, then executes the `return` statement so *it always returns during the first iteration*.
- `for` loop needs to iterate until `i < coinArray.length`
- The loop as written is iterating *once too many* for the value in the `return` statement to be correct.

Here is a version that corrects those issues:

```js
function calculateOrder() {
  var coinArray = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
  var orderSize = 500;
  var sum = 0;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < coinArray.length; i++) {
    if (sum + coinArray[i] > orderSize) {   // if orderSize is exceeded
      return i + ((orderSize - sum) / coinArray[i]); // 2 + (0.66)
    }
    sum += coinArray[i]; // else add to sum 
  }
}

document.write(calculateOrder());
```